# @font-face font doesn't display corectly

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I am currently using Roboto Condensed font for my website with google link directly on the php pages. Instead of the link I want to use @font-face so downloaded the fonts from fontsquirrel and added this code into my css (was the only one that worked):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed';
  src: local('Roboto Condensed'), local('RobotoCondensed-Light-webfont'), url('roboto-fontfacekit/roboto_lightcondensed_macroman/RobotoCondensed-Light-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), url('roboto-fontfacekit/roboto_lightcondensed_macroman/RobotoCondensed-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('roboto-fontfacekit/roboto_lightcondensed_macroman/RobotoCondensed-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't matter which type of font I link to (light, normal, italic or bold) it always looks like the normal one. 
Also the light one has by default a weight of 300. When I had the link from google directly on page I've made the font with a weight of 200 as it was looking better to me. But now I can't.

I tried adding font weight to the above code or changing the code from classes but no changes.

Does anyone know what the problem is and how can this be fixed?
Thanks.

Comment: `@font-face` can contain `font-style` and `font-weight` properties. Did you try using those?

Comment: Yes, tried them and like mentioned above nothing changed when I used font-weight.

Comment: In that case, you should show some more code, the minimum required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I kind of made it work without using the  google link and the @font-face code. Instead of "Roboto Condensed" in all classes I changed it to just "Roboto" and is working fine(checked the website on mobile as well and is ok). So now I have two fonts(Roboto and Pacifico) that work without any links. Are these standard fonts like Arial that are/work on all devices? If yes, then these should work without problems in all browsers, right?

Comment: No, neither Roboto nor Pacifico are installed by default on average computers.